# How to compare an old Dataframe with a new Dataframe row by row (if there isn't a match then I need to insert blank row)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to compare one old df (left) and a new df (right) but the result some time expected and sometime unexpected. Here is the two example df. (_1 = old ,_2 = new) Result_1 = (TRUE = present in both DF, FALSE = Present in old df, absent in new)  Result_2 = (TRUE = present in both DF, FALSE = Present in new df, absent in old)
**Results are generating by the code data frame only having ID,NAME and INFO**
**Both data frames are sorted by the NAME**
** ID_1 and ID_2 are just for distinguish, in Dataframe both are ID **
compare by name

```
    OLD_DF                          NEW_DF
ID_1 NAME_1 INFO_1 Result_1 ||  ID_2 NAME_2 INFO_2  Result_2
 a0   ahku   salt   FALSE   ||   a0   acnt   chry    FALSE 
 a1   amzn   bean   TRUE    ||   a1   amzn   bean    TRUE
 a2   bing   appl   TRUE    ||   a2   bing   appl    TRUE 
 a3   bokt   kiwi   FALSE   ||   a3   bugi   orng    FALSE
 a4   gmal   soya   TRUE    ||   a4   gmal   soya    TRUE
 a5   Huop   peas   FALSE   ||   a5   Hdgw   hrpo    FALSE 
                            ||   a6   Vnew   mush    FALSE
```

I expecting a output like, where not matching the row data insert a blank row in both DF:
it need to be sorted by name while inserting blank line, like (ref_pt)

```
    OLD_DF                          NEW_DF 
ID_1 NAME_1 INFO_1 Result_1 ||  ID_2 NAME_2 INFO_2  Result_2
                            ||   a0   acnt   chry    FALSE   (not present in old so blank line) (ref_pt)
 a0   ahku   salt   FALSE   ||                                    
 a1   amzn   bean   TRUE    ||   a1   amzn   bean    TRUE
 a2   bing   appl   TRUE    ||   a2   bing   appl    TRUE 
 a3   bokt   kiwi   FALSE   ||   
                            ||   a3   bugi   orng    FALSE
 a4   gmal   soya   TRUE    ||   a4   gmal   soya    TRUE
 a5   Huop   peas   FALSE   ||   
                            ||   a5   Hdgw   hrpo    FALSE 
                            ||   a6   Vnew   mush    FALSE
```

[output final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faB3c.png)

can anyone help me out on this please !!!

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question this should work:

```
olddf['results_1'], newdf['results_2'] = [row in newdf.values for row in olddf.values], [row in olddf.values for row in newdf.values]
```

Comment: hey sayan, i posted the desired output, please have a look on it.  results are already producing by me. i need help in the output. please check the output_final. result should be compared by names. for your ans.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dataframe_difference(old_df, new_df, which='both'):

    comparison_df = old_df.merge(new_df, indicator=True, how='outer')
    if which is None:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] != 'both']
    else:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == which]

    return diff_df
```

This piece of code will compare each row for your dataframes, but I'm not sure if it works when your dataframes have different column/index names

Comment: hey kevin , i just add _1 nd _2 as suffix, in df i'ts ID as it is. applied for all

Comment: hey kevin, i  posted the expected output please have a look in that, i do not need the difference, i need to insert the empty row.  if not matching in both old and new. and next i will write to excel.